# Submitting an "old" rejected manuscript to the same journal even though method and conclusion are different?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission

I have submitted a manuscript to a journal before, but they rejected it. I have rewritten the manuscript in the sense that the title, the method, and the conclusion are different. The new manuscript is the same as the old one only in the introduction part. I have read the policy of the journal and they don't accept a rejected manuscript, but can they view my new manuscript as the old one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a new paper, then you need a new introduction. You can freely "self-plagiarize" from things that you previously submitted but not published, but might cause the editor or associate editor who remembers your previous manuscript to read the first page and decide falsely that this is the same manuscript as the one rejected.

Comment: And, really, if the method and conclusion are different one would think that the introduction would be at least slightly different as well - the new paper is heading down a different road and the signposts should not point in the old direction.